# Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config

Tags: ruby, windows, imagemagick

While trying to install ImageMagick on Windows through `msys.bat` by running

```
ruby setup.rb install
```

I'm getting this error:

> setup.rb:787: use `rbconfig` instead of obsolete and deprecated config.
>   no such file or directory -.config
>   `setup.rb config` first
>   Try `ruby setup.rb --help` for detailed usage

Answer (score 2):

RbConfig is a Module which gives access to mostly compile time properties of the current Ruby implementation. To use RbConfig one has to `require 'rbconfig'`. In earlier versions of Ruby this class was just called Config and was loaded through `require 'config'`. When trying to use Config nowadays, Ruby will give out a deprecation warning.

Go into your `setup.rb` into line 787. There you will probably find a `require 'config'`. Change that into a `require 'rbconfig'`. If that doesn't make the script run or there are still warnings, search and replace usages of the Config module with RbConfig. Then Ruby will shut up.

The problem probably only appears the software you are trying to compile is not up to date. I guess an even better way to make it work would be to find a more current version of it, which may solve additional problems.

Comment: just a little side question: could anyone tell me why on windows I do not need to require 'rbconfig' to use say: puts RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'] (which correctly outputs: mingw32)? ruby -v #=> ruby 1.9.3p28 Thanks.

Comment: where is the setup.rb on linux?

Comment: @jpganz18 `setup.rb` should be provided by the software package to be compiled in is usually in the base directory of the distributed archive.

Comment: @jj_ There are a lot of different binary distributions of Ruby for Windows which ship with various tweaks. Most probably any of these tweaks is automatically executed before your actual code is executed. This tweak may already have executed the line `require 'rbconfig'`

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem solved it through:

**@aef's** answer and ther changing the file to look like below:

```
require 'tempfile'

if i = ARGV.index(/\A--rbconfig=/) then
  file = $'
  ARGV.delete_at(i)
  require file
  require 'rbconfig'
else
  require 'rbconfig'
end
```